# When you use X forwarding to run an application on another computer, which processor does it use?

Tags: ssh, xorg, x11-forwarding

If I use `ssh -X` to run an application from Computer A on the screen of Computer B, how are the computation and resources divided up between the two computer's processors?

- Sometimes the audio will play on Computer B, for instance, and sometimes it will play on Computer A, depending on configuration
- Anything that depends on DBus won't work over the connection.
- Text editor Open... dialog sees the files on Computer A

It's kind of confusing.

Also, which is the "server" and which is the "client"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The computer that displays the application on its monitor (computer B) is the *X server*. The other computer (A) is the *ssh server*. What is the server depends on the context, but personally, I would usually mention the ssh server (A) as the “server”.

Computer B uses some resources to draw the windows (and if you have configured it: play sound), while computer A will do all other computation.

Usually, computer B's work requires less resources than computer A's. Computer A will do most of the work, and just send the results to B: Draw a line here, color this area black, etc.

Read the article [X Window System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) at Wikipedia to learn more about X servers and clients.