# Ubuntu: Run X server on a remote server

Tags: ubuntu, x-windows, x-server

How to configure X server on the remote system.

Comment: Be careful what to call a server here. See Simen's explanation at http://superuser.com/questions/70578/when-you-use-x-forwarding-to-run-an-application-on-another-computer-which-proces/70591#70591

Answer (score 2):

The [article here](http://www.quietearth.us/articles/2006/08/24/Ubuntu-Enabling-remote-Xwindows) mentions:

> By default remote x-windows (port
>   6000) is disabled in Ubuntu. Now one
>   easy way around this is just to use
>   ssh to login with port forwarding like
>   such:
>
> ```
> $ ssh -X host
> ```
>
> This will set the
>   DISPLAY variable automatically and any
>   X program you run will be
>   automatically tunneled back through
>   the ssh connection.
>
> Otherwise we're going to need to
>   enable it. Here's how:
>
> 1. Go to System->Administration->Login Window (or run gdmsetup as root)
> 2. Under the security tab uncheck "Deny TCP connections to Xserver"
> 3. Now we have to restart gdm which will kill our Xsession.
>
>    ```
>    kill -HUP `cat /var/run/gdm.pid`
>    ```
>
> or if you prefer to edit `/etc/gdm.conf`
>   by hand, make sure there are no
>   overriding settings in
>   `/etc/gdm.conf-custom`. Under the
>   security section change `DisallowTCP` to
>   false.

Comment: Nuts, I don't see a security tab in that menu.  Editing /etc/gdm/gdm.schemas in the obvious way, then restarting gdm, seems to have worked.